# Android EditText with different floating label and placeholder

Tags: android, material-design

How can i create an editText that looks like this?

[image: Edit Text with placeholder and label]

Answer (score 27):

You can do this using `TextInputLayout` and `EditText`.

**Here is your XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Label">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**1.** Add attribute `android:hint="Label"` to `TextInputLayout` to show its hints `Label` always.

**2.** Programmatically set `EditText` hints `Placeholder` only when `EditText` get focused.

**Add below lines in your Activity:**

```
    .........
    .................

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                editText.setHint("Placeholder");
            } else {
                editText.setHint("");
            }
        }
    });

    .........
    ..................
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Is there a way to keep the label and placeholder like the screenshot in unfocused state?

Comment: Yes its possible. Use `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to parent/container layout.

Comment: Floating label and hint do work, but I need to tap twice on the field in order to show up the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: @andreasimeoni - use `focusableInTouchMode="false"` to prevent the double-tap issue. When you set `focusableInTouchMode` to`true` you're telling the View that it should _only_ focus the view on first tap, without performing the action (showing the keyboard in this case), resulting in the user needing to tap the View twice to show the keyboard. A different example of this would be setting `focusableInTouchMode`  to `true` on a `Button` doing so would require 2 taps for `onClickEvent` to be called  - since the first tap _only_ focuses views when `focusableInTouchMode="true"`.

Comment: @andreasimeoni - I usually solve these "automatic focus" issues that occur by focusing the layouts parent/root view when created or whenever I need to remove focus from a view in a layout. You'll need to give the parent/root Layout an `android:id` and set `focusable="true"` on it, NOT `focusableInTouchMode` on the parent/root layout.

Answer (score 14):

With the Material Components Library you can use:

- **`app:placeholderText`**: to add a placeholder text in the EditText
- **`android:hint`**: to add a floating label

They can work together:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="Label"
        app:placeholderText="Placeholder Text"
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Comment: note that this will only work when the edit text is in focus. when not in focus, the hint  ("label") will show instead of the placeholder

Answer (score 8):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Label">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:hint="Placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Notice that `android:hint="Placeholder"` from `TextInputEditText` is visible at the same time with `android:hint="Label"` from `TextInputLayout` when view is not focused. You could do some extra checking in your java code to show and hide that label. Or just leave `android:hint="Placeholder"` from `TextInputLayout`.

To change color, you need to set a theme using `android:theme="@style/TextLabel` for `TextInputLayout` and there set your color accent.

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

As i know, best possible way how to solve this task with 2 different texts (placeholder and hint) together is to use the code below:

```xml
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintEnabled="true" // enable hint/placeholder on EditText
            android:hint="@string/title_of_input" // title shown above EditText
            app:expandedHintEnabled="false" // disable move placeholder to hint place
            app:placeholderText="@string/placeholder_for_edittetx" // placeholder shown in EditText when no text is filled by user
>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code (in kotlin). It will show placeholder after 200 ms delay (to avoid overlapping hint and placeholder).

```
class PlaceholderEditText : TextInputEditText {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val placeholder = hint

    init {
        hint = ""
        onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                postDelayed({ hint = placeholder }, 200)
            } else {
                hint = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in layout xml class:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="ALWAYS VISIBLE LABEL">

        <com.myapp.widget.PlaceholderEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="DISAPPEARING PLACEHOLDER" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**GIVEN: A `TextInputEditText` nested in `TextInputLayout`!**

**TL;DR!:** Use this Kotlin Extension Function

```
fun EditText.setHintAndLabel(
        textInputLayout: TextInputLayout,
        label: String?, // hint in the TextInputLayout
        hint: String? // hint in the EditText
) {
    this.hint = ""
    textInputLayout.hint = label

    this.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            this.hint = hint ?: ""
        } else {
            this.hint = ""
        }
    }
}
```

**What's the problem and how does it solve it?**

The Problem is that the hint of the `EditText` gets overlapped if there is a hint in the `TextInputLayout`. Which one to show in this case? Good question: We only want the `EditText`'s hint to be displayed when it's focused/the cursor is inside but the `TextInputLayout` hint to be displayed always.

⮑ So we only set the hint for the `EditText` when it has the focus and remove it once it loses focus

Answer (score 0):

You can use below layout xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="Label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:hint="Placeholder" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use textinputlayout then on focus of edittext, you didn't get any placeholder.

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You have to set a focus change listener of the edittext.

**Java:**

```
usernameTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            usernameTxt.setHint("Label");
        } else {
            usernameTxt.setHint("Placeholder");
        }
    }
});
```