# EditText with TextInputlayout layout With hint and Border

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

[image]

I want `EditText` like one in above image. The problem is that if I use `TextInputLayout` it shows default bar at the bottom and I want it with custom borders around it.

I also tried using the below examples,

[Custom TextInputLayout android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891219/custom-textinputlayout-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounded rectangle background editext with hint in left top of background border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564749/rounded-rectangle-background-editext-with-hint-in-left-top-of-background-border)

Comment: That is static solution for fixed hint "Name". i am using multiple EditTexts with different length hints like "Description" , "Age" etc. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either using vector drawable as background of TextView or by the following method:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextround"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

edittextround.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Yeah Mr.Brown.. I have.. Its working for me.. Let me know your feedback..

Comment: see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453570/android-textinputlayout-hint-overlaps-edittext-hint/47835782#47835782)

Answer (score 34):

Use the Material Design Outline Box style

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

See the design guide [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)