# how can i customize an edittext?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

```
var tel_text = "Enter your phone number"
```

Consider that the edittext is tel_text with a large font. When the user starts writing this article in edittext, I want it to be animated from bottom to top. How can I customize Edittext the easiest?

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164170/android-edittext-with-different-floating-label-and-placeholder ??

Comment: @NileshRathod yeah i was looking for something like this thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add a hint to it which animates to the top when user begins to type. Wrap it inside TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/edt_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter your phone number">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```